# Java; Won't connect to the database with correct details?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, web-applications

I've created a user called "root@localhost" in phpMyadmin

My hibernate.cfg.xml looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/autorepairshops</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property> 
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Still I get this exception when it tries to connect to the database:

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Also my root@localhost has all privledges and no password.

Comment: what about when adding `<property name="hibernate.connection.password"/>` to the config?

Comment: Why not set a password and try with a password. Any error messages then?

Comment: @Farhęg i've tried both of your comments, still getting the same error...

Comment: what about required `privileges`!? have you granted them to root on localhot? I mean have you tried `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';`?